# How to pass strings in URL to get the result

Tags: r

I want to add strings in name

```
r=GET("https://genderapi.io/api?name=jyoti")
content(r)$gender
#female
```

I just want to pass different name in place of 'jyoti' like

```
N="jyoti"
```

Then

```
r=GET("https://genderapi.io/api?name=N")
```

After execution it give the result NULL but want as a female in my result to see the gender.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can create a function and concatenate the `name` with the url using `paste0`/`paste`/`str_c` and use `GET`. We can then return any information needed from the `content`.

```
library(httr)

get_gender <- function(name) {
  r = GET(paste0("https://genderapi.io/api?name=", name))
  content(r)$gender
}

get_gender("Jyoti")
#[1] "female"

get_gender("Ronak")
#[1] "male"
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `glue` to insert the values in the string

```
library(httr)
N <- "jyoti"
r <- GET(glue::glue("https://genderapi.io/api?name={N}"))
content(r)$gender
#[1] "female"
```

---

It can be wrapped in a function as well

```
f1 <- function(name) {
 r <- GET(glue::glue("https://genderapi.io/api?name={name}"))
 content(r)$gender
 }

f1(N)
#[1] "female"
```